# get keys of KeyValuePair List to int[] array using linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Having a `List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>` called Info

```
1  Sur
2  Hn
3  uh
4  er
5  Sur
```

I want to get all ids that have as Value string `"Sur" (1,5)` and then convert this result to int array.

I was trying something like

```
int[] productsArray = Info.Select(kvp => kvp.Key ).Where(x => x.ToString () == "Sur").ToArray();
```

As I understand, the x In query is comparing the  keys with "Sur" and that is incorrect.

How to correctly get integer array from a kind of query like that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this

```
List<KeyValuePair<int,string>> infos;

int[] keys = infos.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == "Sur").Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is your answer. I feel that you have written query some wrong way.

```
  info.Where(cc => cc.Value == "Sur").Select(cc => cc.Key).ToArray();
```